# AWS Loadbalancer Targer group pod Readiness: connection refuse

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I setup AWS eks cluster with eksctl with AWS Load Balancer Controller
Depoloyment is runnung simple Nestjs App on port 300
Problem is that  target group in readiness return  connection refuse an unhealthy
kubectl version 1.23.6
eksctl version : 0.165.0

Describe from pod

```
ubectl describe pod techcare-apigw-7f5487b86c-flf8p -n techcare                                                                                                               ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  12:21:22  
Name:         techcare-apigw-7f5487b86c-flf8p
Namespace:    techcare
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-93-25.eu-central-1.compute.internal/192.168.93.25
Start Time:   Sun, 10 Dec 2023 12:15:07 +0100
Labels:       app=techcare-apigw
              pod-template-hash=7f5487b86c
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.72.84
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.72.84
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/techcare-apigw-7f5487b86c
Containers:
  techcare-apigw:
    Container ID:   containerd://2f2b2cf4870d783d9572307f8f3729f4e3fdd40722771d91b1e92b65eb3fcc76
    Image:          435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.66
    Image ID:       435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway@sha256:1cdeab8e0a1db87ad79652b5887d0b961498dcf43a7f06a3ff4e05aec792306a
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 10 Dec 2023 12:15:08 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     400m
      memory:  500Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      400m
      memory:   500Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:3000/health delay=180s timeout=180s period=180s #success=1 #failure=180
    Readiness:  http-get http://:3000/healthz delay=180s timeout=180s period=180s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      PORT:  3000
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n28wz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-n28wz:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  12m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned techcare/techcare-apigw-7f5487b86c-flf8p to ip-192-168-93-25.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling    12m                   kubelet            Pulling image "435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.66"
  Normal   Pulled     12m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.66" in 131.403771ms (131.413766ms including waiting)
  Normal   Created    12m                   kubelet            Created container techcare-apigw
  Normal   Started    12m                   kubelet            Started container techcare-apigw
  Warning  Unhealthy  16s (x10 over 8m13s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.72.84:3000/healthz": dial tcp 192.168.72.84:3000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  16s (x3 over 6m16s)   kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.72.84:3000/health": dial tcp 192.168.72.84:3000: 
connect: connection refused
```

Describe from service

```
kubectl describe service techcare-apigw-s -n techcare                                                                                                                    ✔  16s  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  12:45:06  

Name:                     techcare-apigw-s
Namespace:                techcare
Labels:                   app=techcare-apigw-s
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=techcare-apigw-s
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=techcare-apigw
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.86.89
IPs:                      10.100.86.89
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32437/TCP
Endpoints:                
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Describe from ingress:

```
kubectl describe ing techcare-apigw -n techcare                                                                                                                                ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  12:56:08  

Name:             techcare-apigw
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        techcare
Address:          k8s-techcare-techcare-398c60dce3-83765040.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  techcare-apigw-s:80 ()
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   techcare-apigw-s:80 ()
Annotations:  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
Events:
  Type    Reason                  Age                From     Message
  ----    ------                  ----               ----     -------
  Normal  SuccessfullyReconciled  46m (x2 over 46m)  ingress  Successfully reconciled
```

Manifest files :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw-s
  namespace: techcare # Specify the correct namespace here
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: techcare-apigw-s
    app: techcare-apigw-s
spec:
  selector:
    app: techcare-apigw
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: techcare-apigw
  annotations:
    linkerd.io/inject: enabled
  namespace: techcare
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: techcare-apigw
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: techcare-apigw
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: 435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.66
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: techcare-apigw
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "500Mi"  # Set the requested memory
              cpu: "0.4"      # Set the requested CPU
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"  # Set the requested memory
              cpu: "0.4"       # Set the CPU limit
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 3000
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            periodSeconds: 180
            timeoutSeconds: 180
            failureThreshold: 180
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 3000
            timeoutSeconds: 180
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            periodSeconds: 180


apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb # Corrected Ingress class name
  defaultBackend: # Define default backend here
    service:
      name: techcare-apigw-s  # Replace with the name of your default backend service
      port:
        number: 80  # Replace with the port number of your default backend service
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: techcare-apigw-s
                port:
                  number: 80
```

when i do port forward kubectl port-forward  techcare-apigw-7f5487b86c-flf8p -n techcare 2000:3000     i get normall 200 response

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What i can see are you have 2 different URLs for liveness and readiness

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 3000
  initialDelaySeconds: 180
  periodSeconds: 180
  timeoutSeconds: 180
  failureThreshold: 180
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 3000
```

so your health endpoint, is it healthz or health? and what request did you do to confirm it's working after port-forward?

In your ALB it defaults on / so it's imported. If you change this health ping on ALB it will not target your right health endpoint as you do inside the container.

inside your ingress, I can see you need the annotations

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path
```

if you need more info about it take a look at https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/

Comment: i habe both in my app returning 200 so i use them all

Comment: Can you update the question with right information then? :) becures i just look on your samples and found some issues